# How would I send a message to a specific channel [Discord.py]

Tags: python-3.x, channel, discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord bot that reacts to messages in a certain channel. However I have not been able to achieve it with my current code. I was told to use get_channel and I tried a couple different ways and it has not work. So How would I use get_channel to only react to messages in a certain channel?

```
if message.content.startswith('@'):
    currevents = get_channel(273977792159416321)
    if message.channel is currevents:
        await client.add_reaction(message, ":nocheck:432565697349025803")
        await client.add_reaction(message, ":yescheck:432565678529052672")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "APSIAbot.py", line 28, in on_message
    currevents = get_channel("273977792159416321")
NameError: name 'get_channel' is not defined
```

Comment: Try using `==` rather than `is`.  Are you using the rewrite branch?  (If you don't know the answer is no).  If not, ids are strings, not integers.  Try `get_channel("273977792159416321")` instead

Comment: Are you getting any errors with your current code? If so, could you add it to your question

Comment: `get_channel` is not defined as a function. You may be trying to use `client.get_channel` instead.